# not able to build dependency tree for varnishagent ?is it an open source?

Tags: varnish

I am not able to install varnish-agent what dependencies are required and what is the procedure to install  varnish-agent such that i already have varnish 4.1 installed and have ubuntu as os.
I have the vagent2-master file in /etc/vagent2-master how to install varnish agent from here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Varnish from the official repository, you might be able to install it via `apt-get install varnish-agent` and all the dependencies should be resolved automatically.

I say that based on the Varnish repository: https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/pool/varnish-4.0/v/varnish-agent/